# Making a http request in the background and update clients

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a page that displays something like a list of scores.
I want to make a background http request to a third-party and return a list of updated scores.
If the scores have changed, I want to update the page so that all clients will get an updated view in near real time.

How would I perform this background job every x minutes and then update the clients?

Looking for a high level design, but more detail in how the background job would work.

Note:  I am running all of this currently on a single node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the async update using phoenix channels. There are couple approaches for periodic update.

I'm hearing a lot of good stuff about [quantum-elixir](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir) for scheduling background tasks. I have not used it personally thought.

I usually just create my own scheduler by creating a GenServer to handle the requests. In the GenServer, I use `Process.send_after`to send an message to myself (the genserver). Upon receiving that event, I do the work, and use the Process.send_after to trigger the next period.

Here is the start of a sample project [sample project](https://github.com/smpallen99/background_scores) that illustrates the concept.

EDIT

The [quantum branch](https://github.com/smpallen99/background_scores/tree/quantum) is a similar example using the [Quantum](https://hex.pm/packages/quantum) package.

Both examples use channels to update all browsers viewing the page in real-time.

Comment: Are you familiar with Phoenix channels? Do you want to see some code?

Comment: You can now review two fully functional examples as described in my edit to my post.